# rm -rf not deleting directories through python fork execl script

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, bash, python-2.7

Hi i am trying to use python's fork and execl to create a new bash process and delete a directory 'temptdir'.

I wrote the following code:

```
import os

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.execl('/bin/rm', 'rm-rf', 'temptdir') # temptdir is a directory in home folder.
```

I am expecting that it would create a new bash process and run the following command in bash:

```
rm -rf temptdir
```

and delete the temptdir directory but it is showing me :

```
rm-rf: temptdir: is a directory
```

**Any idea why it is not deleting the directory? Also how to fix it?**

Lastly, on python docs the fortmat of python execl command is given to be:

```
execl(  path, arg0, arg1, ...)
```

but if I run:

```
os.execl('/bin/echo','hello')
```

it doesn't print anything. **Why do I have to add an extra 'echo' argument** like:

```
os.execl('/bin/echo','echo','hello')
```

Comment: try with subprocess

Comment: why not use [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=rmtree#shutil.rmtree)? or why not start with a `tempdir` from the beginning (see [last example here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempdir#examples))?

Comment: Why would you expect python to create a `bash` process?  You are trying to call the `rm` program, not `bash`.  Actually you are trying to call a program called `rm-rf`, which (probably) does not exist.

Comment: *Why do I have to add an extra 'echo' argument* - because python is mirroring the low-level C interface.  A program expects its own name as the first argument, that's in the POSIX standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments separately. As `-r` and `f` are separate arguments to `rm`.

```
import os

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.execl('/bin/rm', 'rm', '-rf', 'temptdir') # temptdir is a directory in home folder.
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: Its always better to check the path where you are doing delete or remove operations..

```
import shutil
import os
dct = "testrmo"
if os.path.exists(dct):
    os.rmdir(dct)   # <--  if directory is blank
    #shutil.rmtree(dct) # <- - if directory has the contents
else:
    print("Sorry, I can not remove %s Dir." % dct)


shutil.rmtree() deletes a directory and all its contents.
```

better use subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['rm', '-rf', 'temptdir'])
```

Just sideby note of using `os` module while playing with files and dirs

```
os.remove() removes a file.

os.rmdir() removes an empty directory.

shutil.rmtree() deletes a directory and all its contents.

pathlib.Path.unlink() removes the file or symbolic link.

pathlib.Path.rmdir() removes the empty directory.
```

another way around is if you need to delete it at all like native way:

```
os.system('rm -rf /your_directory_path/')
```

Comment: Note that `os.system()` invokes a shell to run the command, the others do not.